# JTable. Deleting rows. Consume the event to not get dispatched further

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I needed to delete rows from a JTable on the delete key-press. So the use case is quite simple, the user select some rows, press the delete key, the rows get deleted. The code is also very simple :

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i = selectedRows.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        tableModel.removeRow(selectedRows[i]);
    }
```

The problem is that after the deletion gets finished we'll hear a sound beep (I'm on windows, typical windows beep), as when pressing the delete key in an empty text box (or when the caret is at the end of the text).
What I thing is happening is that the key press is dispatched further to the text component that displays the text content of the cell(the first cell after the deleted ones). The beep is fired by the DefaultEditorKit$DeleteNextCharAction#actionPerformed method because there is no character ahead the dot.
As a hack I modify the event in the listener :

```
e.setKeyCode(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) // see JTable#processKeyBinding
```

the event does not get forwarded further, so the beep dissapear but I think it's a bad solution and there's a better one. But which is that better solution ?

Comment: Have you tried consuming the event instead? `e.consume();`?

Comment: yeah, it's the right answer,  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use key bindings instead...

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "DeleteRow");
am.put("DeleteRow", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Delete row");
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();

        if (row > -1) {

            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            model.removeRow(row);

        }

    }
});
```

(I borrowed mKorbel data for my test, so my test was using a `DefaultTableModel`, you will need to cast to the model you are using).

Also, if you editing, this may still fire, so you will need to check for that

Answer (score 4):

- your core for removing rows is wrong, have to start with Max index, otherwise deleted unselected row,

code example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RemoveAddRows extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)},
        {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)},
        {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)},
        {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)},
        {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)},
        {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)},
        {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)},
        {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)},
        {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)},
        {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)},
        {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)},
        {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)}
    };
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public RemoveAddRows() {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Remove all rows");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i = selectedRows.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                    model.removeRow(selectedRows[i]);
                }
                /*if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
                for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                model.removeRow(i);
                }
                }*/
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Add new rows");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Object[] data0 = {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)};
                model.addRow(data0);
                Object[] data1 = {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)};
                model.addRow(data1);
                Object[] data2 = {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)};
                model.addRow(data2);
                Object[] data3 = {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)};
                model.addRow(data3);
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.add(button1);
        southPanel.add(button2);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoveAddRows frame = new RemoveAddRows();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

- I'm Win user and never heard beep from Win Platform, have to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: it's a contiguous selection every time (sry, forget to tell that), anyway, the consume() method it's the right answer

Comment: changed the question to contain your version of removing since it is better

Comment: no reason to consume() any of mouse or keyboard events, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  generated output to PC's speaker

Comment: even in your own example click on some row and press the delete key, you'll hear the beep

Answer (score 0):

This is [MadProgrammer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) code but I modified it to work with multiple selected rows at once instead of one by one:

```
    // Assume table is a JTable instance
    InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED);
    ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "DeleteRow");
    actionMap.put("DeleteRow", new AbstractAction()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int[] row = table.getSelectedRows();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
            {
                ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(row[i] - i * 1);
            }
        }
    });
```