# how to show data in jTable in JAVA it append old value

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox, jtable

I am using jTable in netbeans. After selection of combobox if i select employee id 1 it show all data of emp 1 in jTable. But next time when i choose emmployee id 2 jTable shows single value of emp id 1's and all another values of empid 2.
My code is given below

```
Connect c       = new Connect();//connection to database
con             = (Connection) c.getConnection();
st              = (Statement)con.createStatement();
String ddate    = (String)text.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println("id " +ddate);
rs = st.executeQuery("select e.employee_id,e.`first_name`, i.outtime, i.outtime_date from tbl_employee e,tbl_outtime i  where e.employee_id=i.outtime_emp_id and i.`outtime_date` LIKE '%/"+month2+"/"+year1+"'and outtime_emp_id="+ddate);
while(rs.next())
{
    String dat1=rs.getString("outtime_date");
    String e1=rs.getString("employee_id");
    System.out.println(e1);
    st33=(Statement) con.createStatement();      
    rs33=st33.executeQuery("select i.intime, i.intime_date from tbl_employee e,tbl_intime
    i where e.employee_id=i.intime_emp_id and i.`intime_date`='"+dat1+"' and 
    i.intime_emp_id="+e1);
    if(rs33.next())
    {
        int emp=rs.getInt("employee_id");
        System.out.println(emp);
        String name=rs.getString("first_name");
        String dept=rs33.getString("intime");
        String desig=rs.getString("outtime");
        String join=rs33.getString("intime_date");
        jTable1.setValueAt(emp, cnt, 0);
        jTable1.setValueAt(name, cnt, 1);
        jTable1.setValueAt(dept, cnt, 2);
        jTable1.setValueAt(desig, cnt, 3);
        jTable1.setValueAt(join, cnt, 4);
        cnt=cnt+1;
    }
}
```

Tell me solution if anyone knows.

Comment: hard to say whatever cleaver, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: oky but can you tell me can i clear jTable while clicking on combobox

Comment: table.setModel(new YourTableModel());

Answer (score 3):

- read tutorial about [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- all data for `JTable`s view are stored into [XxxTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)
- [have to clear XxxTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12263298/714968), and add new row(s) from `JDBC` to the `XxxTableModel`

Answer (score 1):

Use TableModel for adding row.

Read

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

for samples.

Answer (score 1):

Like all other Swing components, a table consists of two parts: a view part (the `JTable`) and a model part (the `TableModel`). The view is updated when the model indicates it has been changed by throwing events. See the [table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

So for your use-case, you can either adjust the existing `TableModel` or create a new one. I would personally opt to create a new one since you are working with a database.

Note that Swing components should only be accessed and modified on the Event Dispatch Thread, and that long running tasks (as querying a database) should not happen on this thread (see the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)). That is why I would recommend to create a new `TableModel`. You can create this model on the worker thread you use for querying the database, and the replace the model in one go on the Event Dispatch Thread. The `SwingWorker` class is most suited for this.