# Problems with deleting values in a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

Okay, so what I have is a GUI with a table set up, (mostly, there are still a few problems) but what I need to know is this. Will the following code:

```
public void removeSelectedRows(JTable table)
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
        for (int x=0;x<rows.length;++x){
            model.removeRow(rows[x]-x);
        }
        for (int x=0;x<animals;++x)
        {
            if (Pets[x][0].equalsIgnoreCase(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0)+""))
            {
                Pets[x][0]=null;
                Pets[x][1]=null;
                Pets[x][2]=null;
                Pets[x][3]=null;
                Pets[x][4]=null;
            }
        }
        animals=animals-1;
    }
```

Delete the row that the user has selected? (By that I mean simply clicking on the row and then clicking the delete button). I don't want the row itself to be deleted but I want the values contained within the row the user has selected to be deleted.

Comment: Once the row has been removed from the table, the selected indices will change. This will effect your `for-loop` from the model and the `Pets`

Comment: Okay. So what could I do to fix that? Do I just get the selected row and then get the first value at that row? Or do I  have to do something more?

Comment: Prepare to get your hands dirty

Answer (score 2):

Get ready to get you hands dirty.

At some point, `DefaultTableModel` will no longer meet your needs and you should be prepared to roll your own implementation.

First things first.  You're working in an Object Orientated language, you should take advantage of this fact and represent your data as objects.

Secondly, when deleting multiple values from a table, it becomes really tricky quickly.  Once you remove the first row, the indices no longer match, you need some way to map the values back to the index that they appear within the model.

Thirdly, the visible row indices may not be the same as those of the model, this is especially true when the table is sorted.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestJTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJTable();
    }

    public TestJTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>(25);
                pets.add(new Pet("Tyrannosauridae", "TYRANNOSAURUS", 20, 35));
                pets.add(new Pet("Dromaeosauridae", "VELOCIRAPTOR", 45, 90));
                pets.add(new Pet("Ceratopsidae", "TRICERATOPS", 15, 30));
                pets.add(new Pet("Stegosauridae", "STEGOSAURUS", 22, 25));
                pets.add(new Pet("Titanosauridae", "MALAWISAURUS", 22, 25));
                pets.add(new Pet("Compsognathidae", "COMPSOGNATHUS", 8, 25));
                pets.add(new Pet("Brachiosauridae", "BRACHIOSAURUS", 8, 25));
                pets.add(new Pet("Diplodocidae", "DIPLODOCUS", 8, 25));

                final PetTableModel model = new PetTableModel(pets);
                final JTable table = new JTable(model);

                InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED);
                ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "delete");
                am.put("delete", new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int[] indices= table.getSelectedRows();
                        // Convert the view's row indices to the models...
                        int[] mapped = new int[indices.length];
                        for (int index = 0; index < indices.length; index++) {
                            mapped[index] = table.convertRowIndexToModel(indices[index]);
                        }
                        model.removePets(mapped);
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PetTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Pet> pets;

        public PetTableModel() {
            pets = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public PetTableModel(List<Pet> pets) {
            this.pets = pets;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return pets.size();
        }

        public void removePets(int... indicies) {
            // Build a tempory list of Pet objects based
            // on the supplied indices...
            List<Pet> old = new ArrayList<>(indicies.length);
            for (int index : indicies) {
                old.add(pets.get(index));
            }

            // For each pet, get it's index in the model
            // remove it from the model
            // notify any listeners of the change to the model...
            for (Pet pet : old) {
                int index = pets.indexOf(pet);
                pets.remove(pet);
                fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            Class clazz = String.class;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    clazz = Float.class;
            }
            return clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            String name = "??";
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    name = "Breed";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    name = "Category";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    name = "Buy Price";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    name = "Sell Price";
                    break;
            }
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Pet pet = pets.get(rowIndex);
            Object value = null;
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = pet.getBreed();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = pet.getCategory();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = pet.getBuyPrice();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    value = pet.getSellPrice();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public void add(Pet pet) {
            pets.add(pet);
            fireTableRowsInserted(getRowCount() - 1, getRowCount() - 1);
        }

    }

    public class Pet {

        private String breed;
        private String category; 
        private float buyPrice; 
        private float sellPrice; 

        public Pet(String breed, String category, float buyPrice, float sellPrice) {
            this.breed = breed;
            this.category = category;
            this.buyPrice = buyPrice;
            this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
        }

        public String getBreed() {
            return breed;
        }

        public float getBuyPrice() {
            return buyPrice;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        public float getSellPrice() {
            return sellPrice;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: And my teacher said it was simply selecting a row and performing a delete subroutine...

Comment: It is, but you need to take into account that when you remove a row, the indices of the other rows will change and that the model may be sorted.

Comment: This is going to be problematic then... As I have no idea what half o the things you are doing are. I seriously am grateful for you helping me like this, but I have no idea what's happening here.

Comment: Debugger is your friend ;)

Comment: [index must be descreasing in all cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12263298/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, but if the you have 5, no sequential rows, how do you now know what the last index would be? - Maths not my friend ;)

Comment: selection can be non_countinious, then you lost index in XxxModel and to remove wrong RowIndex, nothing else :-)

Comment: btw SelectionModel retuns RowIndex by default